# Maxima and minima of $f(x)=\binom{16-x}{2x-1}+\binom{20-3x}{4x-5}$.

Tags: functions, optimization, factorial

Find the maximum and minimum value of the function $f(x)=\binom{16-x}{2x-1}+\binom{20-3x}{4x-5}.$

ATTEMPT:-

By A.M.-G.M. inequality, $\frac{a+b}{2}\ge\sqrt{ab}$, $\quad$ for $a,b\gt 0$ with equality at $a=b.$

For minimum value, $\binom{16-x}{2x-1}=\binom{20-3x}{4x-5}.$

$\qquad$$\implies x=2.$

But when I use my graphing calculator, I get a different result.Where am i going wrong?

And how do I calculate the maximum value?

Comment: If the binomial coefficients involved were "larger" (in the sense of bigger values in the upper part), I'd be tempted to consider the [normal approximation to a binomial distribution](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch07-bin.html) as a way of getting a continuous analog to this discrete problem.  But that seems to be overkill here.  You have only a few $x$ values to check, and the graphing calculator to help you, so see if that gives a better answer than your arithmetic-geometric mean approach.

Comment: I don't think you explained that approach (or shared the calculator output) well enough for me to comment in more detail.

Comment: @yasir : When you write $\binom nm$, does it satisfy $n\ge 0,m\ge 0$ and $n-m\ge 0$ where $n,m\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @mathlove: It's not specified in the problem.

Comment: @hardmath: For $\binom{n}{m}$, if $n\ge 0,m\ge 0$ and $n-m\ge 0$, where $n.m\in Z$, $x \in {{2,3}}$ with minima at $2$. and maxima at $3.$

Comment: Yes, that looks good.  I get $f(2)=728,f(3)=1617$.  Do you wish to post an Answer, so future Readers will benefit from your reasoning?

Comment: @hardmath: Imposing the conditions makes the question quite trivial. I am wondering what if for $\binom{n}{m}$, $n,m\notin Z$.or $n,m\le 0$ How do we find the minima then, that's my real question.

Comment: Okay, I'll put together an Answer based on the normal approximation I mentioned.

Comment: If you're looking at $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the function is unbounded above and below. The function grows to $+ \infty$ on the odd positive integers, and to $-\infty$ on the even integers. You can probably show this by playing around with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_negative_integers) and Stirling's approximation (although I haven't tried).